# how save captchas in the picturebox

Tags: javascript, c#, httpwebrequest, bots, recaptcha

i want to give a captcha for [this site](http://www.travian.com/index.php?server=com1#register) .

i sent a requst with httpwebrequest  for the : http://www.travian.com/index.php?server=com1#register

but i cannt find captcha url in the response of this request.

maybe link captcha created for java script?

please help me for find this captcha link with httpwebrequest .

best regards .

Comment: The captcha is most certainly created with Javascript. You might have some luck with [Selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Comment: ok . how i can create captcha link for httpwebrequest ?